# Failed to register service worker

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have a problem with the register service worker.

When I run my service worker in `localhost` to test him I see this error:

```
dont Activated: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

This is my service worker registration code - all this code in app.js file:

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator
     .serviceWorker
     .register('/service-worker.js').then(registration => {
         console.log('Service worker has been Activted  :' , registration);
     }).catch(err => {
         console.log('dont Activated:' , err )
     })
} else {
    console.log('Servise workers not actived')
}
```

My service-worker.js file is in my root folder!

I linked all the files carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your webserver on https. Service workers can be troublesome if you are not using https.